# Maximum number of user in server IIS

Tags: iis

How many user can enter a site at a time in IIS?
Say, the limit is 100.

Does it mean that 100 user each having various number of request can enter a site?
or
100 user each having a single request can enter a site?
or
100 request are allowed, doesn't matter whether they are from 100 user or not.

Answer (score 0):

Total requests to the server so 100 users at one time.

Controls the number of simultaneous HTTP connections (and hence limits number of simultaneous connections serviceable by IIS6).

•On Windows Server 2003 RTM x86, this comes out to around 8,700

•On Windows Server 2003 SP1, the limit has been removed

•On Windows Server 2003 SP1 x64, since NPP is bound by available memory, you can increase concurrent connections by merely adding more RAM. To give a sense of scope - I have seen 50K+ concurrent connections to IIS6 on WS03SP1 x64 with 4GB RAM

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters

Type: DWORD

Value: Range from 0 to 2^32-1

Why do you have it set so low?
What IIS are you using?

Comment: actually i am not using iis at this moment. I want to clear some of my misconceptions before starting. I mentioned 100 user just for example

Comment: IIS 8 an > is Unlimited on servers